# Como fazer URL amigável sem o mod_rewrite do apache?

Tags: php, url-amigavel

Estou com um pequeno projeto pra fazer nos próximos dias e meu cliente tem uma hospedagem barata, compartilhada, que não me permite alterar as configurações do apache e não está com `mod_rewrite` habilitado. Eu gostaria de encontrar outra forma de manter as URLs amigáveis e estou pensando em arquitetar um ambiente onde:

```
http://www.meucliente.com/action/param1/param2/
```

é substituído por:

```
http://www.meucliente.com/?/action/param1/param2/
```

Note o ponto de interrogação antes de `/action`.

A partir disto o `index.php` vai ler a superglobal `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` pra decidir o que fazer. Até mesmo um formulário com `POST` seria enviado a um endereço que parece um `GET`.

```
<form action="/?/form-action/" method="POST">...</form>
```

#### Aqui vem a verdadeira dúvida:

Na opinião de vocês isso fica com muita cara de gambiarra?
Existe outra forma mais elegante de fazer a URL amigável sem o `mod_rewrite` do apache?

Comment: Você conssegue fazer o uso htaccess? Ou é somente o mod_rewrite que não esta habilitado? pois caso consiga usar o htaccess você pode criar um handler e mandar outro tipo de arquivo ser interpretado como php...

Comment: Vou me atualizar e pesquisar como faz isso que sugeriu, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma técnica válida para os casos onde não tem disponível a reescrita de URL, seja pelo Apache, Nginx, IIS ou qualquer outro servidor.

Isso é chamado de "url amigável falsa". Ou "fake mod_rewrite". Por fim, não existe um termo "oficial". Normalmente encontrará informações sobre o assunto se buscar por esses termos.

Outro modo de fazer é

```
http://www.foo.bar/index.php/action/param1/param2/
```

Na verdade, dá na mesma que usar o modo como apresentou na pergunta, usando parâmetro argumentador vazio.

Nem tudo que é feito com gambiarras representa algo ruim ou amador.

Os frameworks populares possuem suporte para essa gambiarra também. Há gambiarras que são úteis e boas e, essa com certeza é boa e útil

Contudo, aplicar URL amigável quando envia requisição pelo método POST não faz sentido.

Comment: Você tem toda razão, não faz sentido usar isso no POST. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, superou minhas expectativas.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo sua dúvida:

> Aqui vem a verdadeira dúvida: Na opinião de vocês, queridos
>   desenvolvedores experientes, isso fica com muita cara de gambiarra?
>   existe outra forma mais elegante de fazer a url amigável sem o
>   mod_rewrite do apache?

Não! Não vejo gambiarra e com base nas suas necessidades, recomendo estudar melhor os **padrões de projetos**: **Front Controller** ou **Controlador Frontal** e **Command**.

Controlador Frontal

A principal função de um controlador frontal em aplicativos baseados na Web é encapsular os ciclos típicos de solicitação `/rota/despacho/resposta` dentro dos limites de uma API facilmente consumível. Repetindo o que o amigo te respondeu acima, a URL seria algo como: `http://www.foo.bar/index.php/action/param1/param2/`.

Esse é o caminho em que você se encontra. Com os padrões mencionados, você ganhará em flexibilidade e reutilização sem redundância de código. Seu *index.php* seria o responsável por tratar todas as solicitações, com base na solicitação específica, instanciaria outros objetos e chamaria métodos para lidar com as tarefas específicas necessárias. Aproveitando para tratar outras coisas se necessário, como por exemplo: segurança e internacionalização.

O encapsulamento de todas as solicitações por meio de um único ponto de entrada é certamente uma maneira eficiente de implementar um mecanismo baseado em comandos. Nos exemplos mais básico, você verá algumas instruções de *switch* para encaminhar e despachar solicitações, embora na produção possa ser necessário recorrer a implementações mais complexas.